# Not sure how to properly update javafx version

Tags: java, javafx

I'm hoping someone can guide me on how to best update my javafx in Intellij so I don't accidentally break my implementation entirely so I can't work on my application.

when I run my application I get the following:
`WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 19 by JavaFX runtime of version 17.0.2-ea`

I know from reviewing other posts that it's because I'm using JDK v19, with SceneBuilder v19 but javafx is v17.

When I go to *File* -> *Project Structure* -> *Libraries*, I've added the path to the *javafx-sdk-19\lib* folder, which I've downloaded from [gluonhq](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), however I see that there is javafx v17 libraries there with *'Maven:'* in front.
I'm worried that if I just remove them, my javafx will completely break.

Can anyone guide me on updating it? I know this is a warning not something that will break my application unless I'm using a specific code update that only appears in v19 but I'd like a clean console to review errors.

Here's a view of my *Project Structure*:
[project structure window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqYg3.png)

Comment: If you're using Maven, then the JavaFX dependencies are likely being declared in the `pom.xml` file. You should update the versions there, not in IntelliJ (unless changing the dependencies in IntelliJ actually changes the POM file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order To Update:
Go To: File -> Project Structure -> Libraries
And Remove that Library,
Then Download The New(Latest) JavaFX Version And Install it.
And Add It To File -> Project Structure -> Libraries, Again Newer One.
And It Wont Break

Comment: Thanks LakshyaK2011, I've done as you directed and my application still runs but without the warning showing... I'm relieved it was so simple :-)

Comment: At least Accept or upvote The Answer if it Works, So Others Will Know It is Answered

Comment: The problem with the solution is it does not fix the root cause (incorrect versions for dependencies in the Maven pom.xml).  So, although it worked in this case, it won’t work on building using Maven from the command line or on re-importing the Maven project into an IDE.

Comment: If You Build It With INTELLIJ It Wont Break, But If You Use Maven, It Will Break since in pom.xml file dependency is of older version, update your pom.xml file so your project can be build by maven.